# Abrir modal desde JS

Tags: javascript, html, modal

estoy  haciendo una consulta la cual  me genera cierta información, implemente un  Modal. para ver más info o algo así. 
el problema esque genero mucho código Html. 
como le puedo hacer para que cuando le de el botón ver más info mande a llamar el modal Y me cargue el resto de la info, reutilizando un solo Modal.

Comment: Podrias dar un ejemplo, la pregunta se puede interpretar de varias formas: Como llamar al modal?, Como traer más datos del server?, Como cambiar los datos en el modal ya contando con los datos en la página? ...

Comment: ¿Utilizas bootstrap o es una implementación propia?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Utilizando el modal de Bootstrap.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Mas informacion en la página de [Bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/).

Comment: saludos te invito a leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer